# Print a global variable using thread

Tags: c, multithreading, cygwin, pthreads

This is my code, I'm scripting it on CodeBlocks, but I'm compiling it on Cygwin. When I execute the code, the final `printf` print me 0, and I can't understand why. I tried everything that I know. I'm in the 4th year of High school. This code take in a int variable (`sec`) and use it to calculate the weight of a film.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

long long int layer=1;

void* res_VGA (void* sec){
    int tempo = (intptr_t) sec;
    int res = 640*480; //resolution
    int frame = res * 3; // the rgb
    long long int  layer = frame * 25; // 25 frame Hz
    layer * tempo;
    layer/1000000000; // I need this for getting the gigabyte
    pthread_exit(0);
}
void* res_HD (void* sec){
    int tempo = (intptr_t) sec;
    int res = 1080*720;
    int frame = res * 3;
    long long int  layer = frame * 25;
    layer * tempo;
    layer/1000000000;
    pthread_exit(0);
}
void* res_FHD (void* sec){
    int tempo = (intptr_t) sec;
    int res = 1920*1080;
    int frame = res * 3;
    long long int  layer = frame * 25;
    layer * tempo;
    layer/1000000000;
    pthread_exit(0);
}
int main(){
    int sec,res;
    pthread_t t1;
    printf("Inserisci il numero di secondi: \n");
    scanf("%d",&sec);
    printf("Seleziona il tipo di risoluzione: \n");
    printf("1) VGA \n");
    printf("2) HD \n");
    printf("3) FHD \n");
    do{
        scanf("%d",&res);
        if(res == 1){
            pthread_create(&t1, NULL, res_VGA, (void*)(intptr_t)sec);
        }
        else if(res == 2){
            pthread_create(&t1, NULL, res_HD, (void*)(intptr_t)sec);
        }
        else if(res == 3){
            pthread_create(&t1, NULL, res_FHD, (void*)(intptr_t)sec);
        }
    }while(res != 1 && res != 2 && res != 3);
    printf("Il film pesa %lld byte", layer/1000000000);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is probable because layer is an `int`instead of a float, and when you divide it by `100000000` it must be `0.xx` and it truncates the answer

Comment: "*the final printf print me 0,*" because the code  prints the result of `1/1000000000` in any case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have multiple problems.

1) Here,

```
  layer * tempo;
  layer/1000000000; // I need this for getting the gigabyte
```

You are computing layer but discard the results!

You probably want:

```
  layer = layer * tempo;
  layer = layer/1000000000;
```

This change needs to be done for all threads.

2) `layer` is of `long long`. So the final division (`layer = layer/1000000000`) could be become zero (due to integer division). Instead use `long double`.

3) You have a local variable `long long int layer;` which shadows the global variable. If you want to store the results (as opposed to computing the value locally and returning the result), then change:

```
long long int  layer = frame * 25;
```

to

```
layer = frame * 25;
```

This change needs to be done for all thread functions.

4) You `main()` thread is not waiting for the other thread to complete. So it might exit before the other thread completes. So you should either call `pthread_exit(0)` or `pthread_join(t1, 0);` in `main()` after creating the thread.

When the `main()` exits, the whole process dies. `pthread_join()` would make it wait for the thread's completion. `pthread_exit()` will make sure only the main thread dies, not the whole process.

Answer (score 0):

`layer/1000000000` will be always `0` because your tasks redefine the `layer` var and will not modify the global one.

Then the translate will be `1/1000000000`, that will be `0` in `long long int`
If you want to avoid that change:

```
long long int  layer = frame * 25;
```

with

```
layer = frame * 25;
```

In all tasks functions.

Another thing is that with

```
layer * tempo;
layer/1000000000;
```

You're not modifying nothing
I think you meant:

```
layer *= tempo;
layer /= 1000000000;
```

As already wrote by `l3x` you at least need to call `pthread_join` for each task you launch to let the `main` waiting for the conclusion of each task.

Comment: Or the process dies before any computation takes place at all.